# Getting error member `add` not found when using ChainlinkClient.sol v0.8.0

Tags: blockchain, chainlink, polygon

I'm trying to use Chainlink `APIConsumer` example and for the same I'm importing `v0.8/ChainlinkClient.sol` file. On compiling `APIConsumer` contract, I'm getting below error.

**ERROR**

```
TypeError: Member "add" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in struct Chainlink.Request memory.
  --> contracts/APIConsumer.sol:44:9:
   |
44 |         request.add("get", "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemultifull?fsyms=ETH&tsyms=USD");
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

It is not showing any error when using `v0.6/ChainlinkClient.sol`.

**Contracts**

***APIConsumer.sol***

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: Unlicense

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/ChainlinkClient.sol";

/**
 * @notice reference link for Polygon-Chainlink API's integration
 * https://docs.matic.network/docs/develop/oracles/chainlink/
 */
contract APIConsumer is ChainlinkClient {
  
    uint256 public volume;
    
    address private oracle;
    bytes32 private jobId;
    uint256 private fee;
    
    /**
     * Network: Matic Mumbai Testnet
     * Oracle: 0x58bbdbfb6fca3129b91f0dbe372098123b38b5e9
     * Job ID: da20aae0e4c843f6949e5cb3f7cfe8c4
     * LINK address: 0x326C977E6efc84E512bB9C30f76E30c160eD06FB
     * Fee: 0.01 LINK
     */
    constructor() {
        //setPublicChainlinkToken;
        setChainlinkToken(0x326C977E6efc84E512bB9C30f76E30c160eD06FB);
        //oracle = 0x58bbdbfb6fca3129b91f0dbe372098123b38b5e9;
        oracle = 0x58BBDbfb6fca3129b91f0DBE372098123B38B5e9;
        jobId = "da20aae0e4c843f6949e5cb3f7cfe8c4";
        fee = 0.01 * 10 ** 18; // 0.01 LINK
    }
    
    /**
     * Create a Chainlink request to retrieve API response, find the target
     * data, then multiply by 1000000000000000000 (to remove decimal places from data).
     */
    function requestVolumeData() public returns (bytes32 requestId) 
    {
        Chainlink.Request memory request = buildChainlinkRequest(jobId, address(this), this.fulfill.selector);
        
        // Set the URL to perform the GET request on
        request.add("get", "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemultifull?fsyms=ETH&tsyms=USD");
        
        // Set the path to find the desired data in the API response, where the response format is:
        request.add("path", "RAW.ETH.USD.VOLUME24HOUR");
        
        // Multiply the result by 1000000000000000000 to remove decimals
        int timesAmount = 10**18;
        request.addInt("times", timesAmount);
        
        // Sends the request
        return sendChainlinkRequestTo(oracle, request, fee);
    }
    
    /**
     * Receive the response in the form of uint256
     */ 
    function fulfill(bytes32 _requestId, uint256 _volume) public recordChainlinkFulfillment(_requestId)
    {
        volume = _volume;
    }
}
```

***v0.8/ChainlinkClient.sol***

Copied it from `node_modules`.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "./Chainlink.sol";
import "./interfaces/ENSInterface.sol";
import "./interfaces/LinkTokenInterface.sol";
import "./interfaces/OperatorInterface.sol";
import "./interfaces/PointerInterface.sol";
import { ENSResolver as ENSResolver_Chainlink } from "./vendor/ENSResolver.sol";

/**
 * @title The ChainlinkClient contract
 * @notice Contract writers can inherit this contract in order to create requests for the
 * Chainlink network
 */
contract ChainlinkClient {
  using Chainlink for Chainlink.Request;

  uint256 constant internal LINK_DIVISIBILITY = 10**18;
  uint256 constant private AMOUNT_OVERRIDE = 0;
  address constant private SENDER_OVERRIDE = address(0);
  uint256 constant private ORACLE_ARGS_VERSION = 1;
  uint256 constant private OPERATOR_ARGS_VERSION = 2;
  bytes32 constant private ENS_TOKEN_SUBNAME = keccak256("link");
  bytes32 constant private ENS_ORACLE_SUBNAME = keccak256("oracle");
  address constant private LINK_TOKEN_POINTER = 0xC89bD4E1632D3A43CB03AAAd5262cbe4038Bc571;

  ENSInterface private ens;
  bytes32 private ensNode;
  LinkTokenInterface private link;
  OperatorInterface private oracle;
  uint256 private requestCount = 1;
  mapping(bytes32 => address) private pendingRequests;

  event ChainlinkRequested(
    bytes32 indexed id
  );
  event ChainlinkFulfilled(
    bytes32 indexed id
  );
  event ChainlinkCancelled(
    bytes32 indexed id
  );

  /**
   * @notice Creates a request that can hold additional parameters
   * @param specId The Job Specification ID that the request will be created for
   * @param callbackAddress The callback address that the response will be sent to
   * @param callbackFunctionSignature The callback function signature to use for the callback address
   * @return A Chainlink Request struct in memory
   */
  function buildChainlinkRequest(
    bytes32 specId,
    address callbackAddress,
    bytes4 callbackFunctionSignature
  )
    internal
    pure
    returns (
      Chainlink.Request memory
    )
  {
    Chainlink.Request memory req;
    return req.initialize(specId, callbackAddress, callbackFunctionSignature);
  }

  /**
   * @notice Creates a Chainlink request to the stored oracle address
   * @dev Calls `chainlinkRequestTo` with the stored oracle address
   * @param req The initialized Chainlink Request
   * @param payment The amount of LINK to send for the request
   * @return requestId The request ID
   */
  function sendChainlinkRequest(
    Chainlink.Request memory req,
    uint256 payment
  )
    internal
    returns (
      bytes32
    )
  {
    return sendChainlinkRequestTo(address(oracle), req, payment);
  }

  /**
   * @notice Creates a Chainlink request to the specified oracle address
   * @dev Generates and stores a request ID, increments the local nonce, and uses `transferAndCall` to
   * send LINK which creates a request on the target oracle contract.
   * Emits ChainlinkRequested event.
   * @param oracleAddress The address of the oracle for the request
   * @param req The initialized Chainlink Request
   * @param payment The amount of LINK to send for the request
   * @return requestId The request ID
   */
  function sendChainlinkRequestTo(
    address oracleAddress,
    Chainlink.Request memory req,
    uint256 payment
  )
    internal
    returns (
      bytes32 requestId
    )
  {
    return rawRequest(oracleAddress, req, payment, ORACLE_ARGS_VERSION, oracle.oracleRequest.selector);
  }

  /**
   * @notice Creates a Chainlink request to the stored oracle address
   * @dev This function supports multi-word response
   * @dev Calls `requestOracleDataFrom` with the stored oracle address
   * @param req The initialized Chainlink Request
   * @param payment The amount of LINK to send for the request
   * @return requestId The request ID
   */
  function requestOracleData(
    Chainlink.Request memory req,
    uint256 payment
  )
    internal
    returns (
      bytes32
    )
  {
    return requestOracleDataFrom(address(oracle), req, payment);
  }

  /**
   * @notice Creates a Chainlink request to the specified oracle address
   * @dev This function supports multi-word response
   * @dev Generates and stores a request ID, increments the local nonce, and uses `transferAndCall` to
   * send LINK which creates a request on the target oracle contract.
   * Emits ChainlinkRequested event.
   * @param oracleAddress The address of the oracle for the request
   * @param req The initialized Chainlink Request
   * @param payment The amount of LINK to send for the request
   * @return requestId The request ID
   */
  function requestOracleDataFrom(
    address oracleAddress,
    Chainlink.Request memory req,
    uint256 payment
  )
    internal
    returns (
      bytes32 requestId
    )
  {
    return rawRequest(oracleAddress, req, payment, OPERATOR_ARGS_VERSION, oracle.requestOracleData.selector);
  }

  /**
   * @notice Make a request to an oracle
   * @param oracleAddress The address of the oracle for the request
   * @param req The initialized Chainlink Request
   * @param payment The amount of LINK to send for the request
   * @param argsVersion The version of data support (single word, multi word)
   * @return requestId The request ID
   */
  function rawRequest(
    address oracleAddress,
    Chainlink.Request memory req,
    uint256 payment,
    uint256 argsVersion,
    bytes4 funcSelector
  )
    private
    returns (
      bytes32 requestId
    )
  {
    requestId = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(this, requestCount));
    req.nonce = requestCount;
    pendingRequests[requestId] = oracleAddress;
    emit ChainlinkRequested(requestId);
    bytes memory encodedData = abi.encodeWithSelector(
      funcSelector,
      SENDER_OVERRIDE, // Sender value - overridden by onTokenTransfer by the requesting contract's address
      AMOUNT_OVERRIDE, // Amount value - overridden by onTokenTransfer by the actual amount of LINK sent
      req.id,
      req.callbackAddress,
      req.callbackFunctionId,
      req.nonce,
      argsVersion,
      req.buf.buf);
    require(link.transferAndCall(oracleAddress, payment, encodedData), "unable to transferAndCall to oracle");
    requestCount += 1;
  }

  /**
   * @notice Allows a request to be cancelled if it has not been fulfilled
   * @dev Requires keeping track of the expiration value emitted from the oracle contract.
   * Deletes the request from the `pendingRequests` mapping.
   * Emits ChainlinkCancelled event.
   * @param requestId The request ID
   * @param payment The amount of LINK sent for the request
   * @param callbackFunc The callback function specified for the request
   * @param expiration The time of the expiration for the request
   */
  function cancelChainlinkRequest(
    bytes32 requestId,
    uint256 payment,
    bytes4 callbackFunc,
    uint256 expiration
  )
    internal
  {
    OperatorInterface requested = OperatorInterface(pendingRequests[requestId]);
    delete pendingRequests[requestId];
    emit ChainlinkCancelled(requestId);
    requested.cancelOracleRequest(requestId, payment, callbackFunc, expiration);
  }

  /**
   * @notice Sets the stored oracle address
   * @param oracleAddress The address of the oracle contract
   */
  function setChainlinkOracle(
    address oracleAddress
  )
    internal
  {
    oracle = OperatorInterface(oracleAddress);
  }

  /**
   * @notice Sets the LINK token address
   * @param linkAddress The address of the LINK token contract
   */
  function setChainlinkToken(
    address linkAddress
  )
    internal
  {
    link = LinkTokenInterface(linkAddress);
  }

  /**
   * @notice Sets the Chainlink token address for the public
   * network as given by the Pointer contract
   */
  function setPublicChainlinkToken() 
    internal
  {
    setChainlinkToken(PointerInterface(LINK_TOKEN_POINTER).getAddress());
  }

  /**
   * @notice Retrieves the stored address of the LINK token
   * @return The address of the LINK token
   */
  function chainlinkTokenAddress()
    internal
    view
    returns (
      address
    )
  {
    return address(link);
  }

  /**
   * @notice Retrieves the stored address of the oracle contract
   * @return The address of the oracle contract
   */
  function chainlinkOracleAddress()
    internal
    view
    returns (
      address
    )
  {
    return address(oracle);
  }

  /**
   * @notice Allows for a request which was created on another contract to be fulfilled
   * on this contract
   * @param oracleAddress The address of the oracle contract that will fulfill the request
   * @param requestId The request ID used for the response
   */
  function addChainlinkExternalRequest(
    address oracleAddress,
    bytes32 requestId
  )
    internal
    notPendingRequest(requestId)
  {
    pendingRequests[requestId] = oracleAddress;
  }

  /**
   * @notice Sets the stored oracle and LINK token contracts with the addresses resolved by ENS
   * @dev Accounts for subnodes having different resolvers
   * @param ensAddress The address of the ENS contract
   * @param node The ENS node hash
   */
  function useChainlinkWithENS(
    address ensAddress,
    bytes32 node
  )
    internal
  {
    ens = ENSInterface(ensAddress);
    ensNode = node;
    bytes32 linkSubnode = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(ensNode, ENS_TOKEN_SUBNAME));
    ENSResolver_Chainlink resolver = ENSResolver_Chainlink(ens.resolver(linkSubnode));
    setChainlinkToken(resolver.addr(linkSubnode));
    updateChainlinkOracleWithENS();
  }

  /**
   * @notice Sets the stored oracle contract with the address resolved by ENS
   * @dev This may be called on its own as long as `useChainlinkWithENS` has been called previously
   */
  function updateChainlinkOracleWithENS()
    internal
  {
    bytes32 oracleSubnode = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(ensNode, ENS_ORACLE_SUBNAME));
    ENSResolver_Chainlink resolver = ENSResolver_Chainlink(ens.resolver(oracleSubnode));
    setChainlinkOracle(resolver.addr(oracleSubnode));
  }

  /**
   * @notice Ensures that the fulfillment is valid for this contract
   * @dev Use if the contract developer prefers methods instead of modifiers for validation
   * @param requestId The request ID for fulfillment
   */
  function validateChainlinkCallback(
    bytes32 requestId
  )
    internal
    recordChainlinkFulfillment(requestId)
    // solhint-disable-next-line no-empty-blocks
  {}

  /**
   * @dev Reverts if the sender is not the oracle of the request.
   * Emits ChainlinkFulfilled event.
   * @param requestId The request ID for fulfillment
   */
  modifier recordChainlinkFulfillment(
    bytes32 requestId
  )
  {
    require(msg.sender == pendingRequests[requestId],
            "Source must be the oracle of the request");
    delete pendingRequests[requestId];
    emit ChainlinkFulfilled(requestId);
    _;
  }

  /**
   * @dev Reverts if the request is already pending
   * @param requestId The request ID for fulfillment
   */
  modifier notPendingRequest(
    bytes32 requestId
  )
  {
    require(pendingRequests[requestId] == address(0), "Request is already pending");
    _;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the line `using Chainlink for Chainlink.Request;` after the contract declaration like so:

```
contract APIConsumer is ChainlinkClient {
    using Chainlink for Chainlink.Request;
  
    uint256 public volume;
    
    address private oracle;
    bytes32 private jobId;
    uint256 private fee;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Zak. it's working now. I have one more query. when we are using `using Chainlink for Chainlink.Request;` then why can't I change
`Chainlink.Request memory request = buildChainlinkRequest(jobId, address(this), this.fulfill.selector);` to `Chainlink memory request = buildChainlinkRequest(jobId, address(this), this.fulfill.selector);`?